# What is the meaning of thermal spectral function and thermal decay width in thermal field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, greens-functions, thermal-field-theory

In Kallen-Lehmann spectral representation of 2-point correlation function 
\begin{equation}
\langle 0|T\phi(x)\phi(0)|0\rangle=\int_0^\infty \frac{dM^2}{2\pi}\rho(M^2)D_F(x-y;M^2),\quad (a)
\end{equation} 
stable particles correspond to isolated poles on the real axis, while unstable particles correspond to poles off the real axis. In the spectral function the peaks of stable particles are $\delta$-functions, while the peaks of unstable particles have a finite width, equal to their decay width. The last point can easily be prove by the optical theorem, see e.g. Peskin P236-237.

My question is about whether the above statements about unstable particles are still valid in the finite temperature region. Let us consider, for example, meson 2-point functions in nuclear medium:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{Z}\mathrm{Tr}\{e^{-\beta(H-\mu N)}T[\phi(x)\phi(0)]\}=\frac{1}{Z}\sum_{all~ \alpha} e^{-\beta (E_\alpha-\mu N_\alpha)}\langle \alpha|T\phi(x)\phi(0)|\alpha\rangle, \quad(b)
\end{equation}
where $\alpha$ sums over all possible states of the NM.

(1). Suppose that a stable state $\phi$ and an unstable one $\phi^*$ can both be created by $\phi(x)$, and there is a decay $\phi^*\to\phi+\gamma$. How to define "thermal decay width"? A naive one is 
\begin{equation}\Gamma_{T,\mu}(\phi^*\to\phi+\gamma)=\frac{1}{Z}\sum_{all~ \alpha} e^{-\beta (E_\alpha-\mu N_\alpha)}\Gamma(\phi^*+\alpha\to\phi+\gamma+\alpha),\quad(c)
\end{equation}
namely the ensemble average of decay width. Is this correct?

(2). Is the thermal spectral function defined similar to (a)?

(3). Is the width of an unstable particle peak in thermal spectral function equal to thermal decay width?

(4). It is very likely that the pole position of the in medium 2-point correlation function also differs from the vacuum case: $\frac{1}{p^2-M^2_0}\to \frac{1}{p^2-M^2_{T,\mu}}$. People say that particles get a "thermal mass" in medium, but what is its physical meaning?